# Is it a best practices to wrap a h:form tag in the jsf template page

Tags: jsf, hyperlink, command, components

```
<p><h:commandLink value="Apply Now" action="register" /></p>
```

when i writing code above, exception below throws:

> [2/12/10 11:24:29:535 CST] 0000005f renderkit     W   Component j_id26 must be enclosed inside a form.

Is it a **best practices** to wrap a h:form tag in the jsf template page, and then every page using the template can just **directly use the h:commandLink tag without hesitate on the h:form tag?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion `<h:form>` and `<f:view>` shouldn't be in the template page, because:

- you can't customize their attributes, like (notably: `enctype` or `beforePhase`)
- you may want multiple forms in a page.
- you may at some point, in some places need to replace `<h:form>` with `<a4j:form>` (for example)

If you have many, very simple pages, then you can make an alternative template, which includes the main template, and which adds `<f:view>` and `<h:form>`.

Comment: agree, but for some case, i just want to have a simple link like the above, i still have to write below code:

    <p><h:form id="register"><h:commandLink value="Apply Now" action="registerUser" /></h:form></p>

anyone can teach me how to style code in comment ;( ?

Comment: +1 essentially for the second point. Even if you can use the `<a4j:region/>` to split your page in separate blocks - for Ajax calls.

Comment: Thanks all for the suggestion ;)